# Скрипт должен нажать yes в диалоговом окне при установке пакета

Tags: python, python-3.x, debian, deb, пакетный-менеждер

Мне нужно чтобы скрипт установил iptables-persistent на машину debian 10. Но при установке появляется диалоговое окно как на картинке, где нужно выбрать да или нет. Из-за чего работа скрипта приостанавливается пока юзер не выберет ответ.

[image: Диалоговое окно]

Я пробовал заставить скрипт нажимать enter, но работа скрипта тормозится установкой. В результате он нажимает клавишу только после завершения установки.

Также пробовал преднастроить пакет с помощью `debconf-set-selections <<< 'iptables-persistent iptables-persistent/autosave_v4 true'`, но мне выдало ошибку что true это какой-то непонятный аргумент, хотя `debconf-show iptables-persistent` выводит именно такие параметры.

Код скрипта:

```
import os
import keyboard

os.system("apt install iptables-persistent -y")
keyboard.send("enter")
keyboard.send("enter")
```

Еще хотелось бы узнать что я сделал не так при преднастройке пакета
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @aleksandr `export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive` прописал, но диалоговое окно не пропало

Comment: `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt ...` будьте внимательнее. либо, если вам нравится именно команда export: `export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive; apt ...`

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin спасибо большое, ввел `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt  install iptables-persistent` и сработало, неправильно потом что имелось ввиду в похожем вопросе